# webpage user sign up with imagetext

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a page for new user sign where i am showing the imagetext for verification to avoid spamming. I am able to dynamically create the imagetext and show it to the user. When the user submits how do associate the input text with the original image text. I dont want to use hidden input elements to store the text. I am using Springs and is there a way Spring can help with this? Any examples or link would greatly help me.

edit

@Rasoul Pashaie 
the link you gave "Integrating Captcha with Spring Security" talks about using third party service like reCaptcha. What i want to do is develop my own service. As i said above i already have a way to produce an image from text. I just need to weave the rest of the part where user will submit and in the backend the validation is done. I am just trying to know how to do this validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you refer as imagetext, is known as CAPTCHA.
you can find out more at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA

And yeah, storing them in hidden input are not a good solution.
You must keep the original text in Session.

for integrating with spring, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217511/integrating-captcha-with-spring-security)

Comment: the link you gave "Integrating Captcha with Spring Security" talks about using third party service like reCaptcha. What i want to do is develop my own service. As i said above i already have a way to produce an image from text. I just need to weave the rest of the part where user will submit and in the backend the validation is done. I am just trying to know how to do this validation.